# Notification throwing intents without it's extras

Tags: android, notifications, android-intent

I am trying to launch an intent from a notification, but for a reason I don't know the extra is not always sent with the intent.
This is where I create the intent :

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,
                    mContext.getString(R.string.text), 0);

Intent intents = new Intent(mContext, DataAppTabs.class);
intents.putExtra(DataAppTabs.REQUEST, DataAppTabs.REQUEST_DMTAB);
intents.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
PendingIntent launchIntent =    PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext.getApplicationContext(), DataAppTabs.REQUEST_DMTAB, intents, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(mContext, "Info", mContext.getString(R.string.enginedmnotification_rebootneeded), launchIntent);
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE;
notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
notificationManager.notify(DataAppTabs.REQUEST_DMTAB, notification);
```

In the DataAppTabs class I overrided onCreate() and onNewIntent(). When the notification appears, if I click on it it opens the correct Activity (DataAppTabs, which is a TabActivity), it triggers onCreate or onNewIntent if the activity was already started, but the extra "REQUEST" is not always set (getExtras() is sometimes null).

I have found the same question here with answers telling me I had to use the "FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP" flag, but it still doesn't work all the time and I am not able to reproduce the problem every time.

Is it something I did wrong ?
Thanks

Comment: I am having the exact same problem.  in my case, I can repro consistently with 2nd notification.  The first notification always works with the correct extras.  Since 2nd notification, all subsequent notifications have null extras.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    // Displaying Notification
              NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
               Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "MyNotification", System.currentTimeMillis());
                PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Sample.class), 0);
                notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), "Notification Title", "Notification Data", contentIntent);
                notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;

                            int NOTIFICATION_ID=(int)System.currentTimeMillis();
                manager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

// Sample.class is the activity to which you want to go when you click on Notification
```

Comment: It did seem to work at first .. but as always, it I try it a few times at some point it doesn't work anymore (extra is not set).

Comment: Intent **intent** = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Sample.class); intent.putExtra("sample","sample");  replace this --> **new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Sample.class)** with this **intent**

Comment: @KK_07k11A0585 I can't make any sense out of your comment.  This is marked as answered but it doesn't seem to work.  Are you able to resolve this?  What's the issue and what's the solution?  I am consistently reproducing the bug that 2nd notifications will always have null extra.  First notification works fine.